# How to achieve live updates in sculpting split view?

Tags: 3d-view, sculpting

Soo, imagine the following scenario:
I am having a head sculpt, that I am working on. I have my viewport view split in two, so I can view the head from the front, as well as from the side at the same time.
However, when I do changes with a sculpt brush from the front view viewport the changes only update on the side view viewport after I am done sculpting, which is annoying, when both perspectives are important.
Is there any way in heaven or hell to have all viewports giving me live updates when sculpting?